# @mui DateRangePicker How to prevent selecting date range in which there is a disabled date in between?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the [daterangepicker](https://mui.com/components/date-range-picker) component from @mui in my project. I can set disabled dates via shouldDisableDate. But I also can select a range that includes these disabled dates.

Is there any way to prevent this conflict?

In the example, the dates between the 23rd and 26th are disabled and yet I can select a range that can include disabled dates
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMkjb.png)

Or is there a date-range-picker component that I can use for react and give it custom dates that should appear as disabled and not select a range that has disabled dates?